# canonical registration id gcm

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

Does anyone now how long the canonical registration id will be sent before that particular registration id becomes deleted and a send error is returned? Once the "old" registration id is deleted I would imagine that no response will come from the Google cloud and instead only an error message will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have old registration id that still works months After I got a newer registration id for that app on my device.  I still get the canonical registration id in the response each time I use the old one, and the notification is delivered.

I've never got an error when using an old registration id, unless I use it after uninstalling the app. But then, after I re-install the app, the old registration id still works (even though the app gets a new registration id).

If Google ever delete the old registration id, I suppose they will return a `NotRegistered` error in their response. Regardless of what error they would return in this case, they always return a response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is any google document about this?

Comment: @Max You're welcome. I read Google's GCM docs more than once, and didn't see any specific answer to your question. All they say is that as some point, the old registration ID would stop working. In all my experiments I haven't managed to reach that point (BTW, their documentation wasn't clear about how to make the app get a new registration id, and thus cause the use of the old registration ID to return a canonical registration ID. I had to experiment with that until I figured it out).